# web2py: custom forms can not edit anymore after submitting

Tags: javascript, web2py, web2py-modules

I am working on a custom project in web2py and I am facing one problems I can not edit submitted data anymore for some reason.

**Controller**

@auth.requires(auth.has_membership(group_id = 'admin') or auth.has_membership(group_id = 'project_manager'))
def update():

```
# select project from table and save in variable projects
project_selected = db.projects(request.args(0, cast=int)) or redirect(URL('index'))
#db.post.projects_id.default = project_selected.id

# create form for projects table and initiate with selected project
form = SQLFORM(db.projects, project_selected)

# create form for activity table
form_activity = SQLFORM(db.activity)
if form_activity.process().accepted:
    response.flash = T('Record Updated')
else:
    response.flash = T('Please complete the form')

# select all activities for the selected project and save in variable
activities_project = db(db.activity.projects_id == project_selected.id).select(orderby=db.activity.id)

return dict(form=form, form_activity=form_activity,  projects=project_selected,  activities_project=activities_project)
```

**strong text**
**View**

```
<br>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tab(event, 'Overview')" id="defaultOpen">Overview</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tab(event, 'Team')">Team</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tab(event, 'Third Parties')">Third Parties</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tab(event, 'Activity')">Activity</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tab(event, 'Files')">Files</button>


</div>

{{=form.custom.begin}}

<div id="Overview" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>General</h3>
  <br>
  <p>Project Name {{=form.custom.widget.project_name}}</p>
  <p>Project Country {{=form.custom.widget.project_country}}</p>
  <p>Equity Share{{=form.custom.widget.equity_share}}</p>
  <p>Strategy Initiative{{=form.custom.widget.strategy_initiative}}</p>
  <br>
  <h3>Technical Data</h3>
  <br>
  <p>Project Technology {{=form.custom.widget.technology}}</p>
  <p>Project Capacity {{=form.custom.widget.capacity_mw}}</p>
  <!-- <p>Energy Generation (Zahl)tausender bereich</p> #Spaeter in DB anlegen 
  <p>Capex(Zahl)tausender bereich </p> -->
  <!-- <p>Project Description</p> --> 
  <br>
  <h3>Development</h3>
  <br>
  <p>Project Development Phase {{=form.custom.widget.project_devlopment_phase}}</p>
  
  <p>Project Initiated {{=form.custom.widget.initiated}}</p>
  <p>Project Expected COD {{=form.custom.widget.expected_cod}}</p>
  <p>Project Status Description {{=form.custom.widget.status_description}}</p>
  <p>Project Status {{=form.custom.widget.status}}</p>
  

</div>
<div id="Team" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Development</h3>
  <p>BD Team{{=form.custom.widget.bd_team}}</p>
  <p>BD Manager{{=form.custom.widget.bd_manager}}</p>
  



</div>
<div id="Third Parties" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Off Taker Name,Land,Type ,E-Mail,Adresse,Plz{{=form.custom.widget.off_taker}}</p> DB erstellen seperat
  <p>Partner=Name, Land, Type, E-Mail,Adresse,Plz</p> DB erstellen seperat
</div>


<div id="Activity" class="tabcontent">

  {{if len(activities_project):}}

  <h2>Activity </h2><br />
  <p>
    {{for activity in activities_project:}}
  <p>{{=projects.project_name}} says <i>{{=activity.body}} Posted on {{=activity.created_on}} by {{=activity.created_by.first_name}}
      {{=activity.created_by.last_name}}</i></p>
  {{pass}}</p>
  {{else:}}
  <h2>No comments posted yet</h2>
  {{pass}}

  {{=form_activity}}
</div>  
{{=form.custom.submit}}
```

{{=form.custom.end}}

```
<script>
  function tab(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }

  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong to be honest it worked but now not anymore

Answer (score 0):

The manual says:
"It is possible to have multiple forms per page, but you must allow web2py to distinguish them."

Try to define a unique name for your forms.

```
form = SQLFORM(db.projects, project_selected, _name="form_projects")
...
form_activity = SQLFORM(db.activity, _name="form_activity")
```

Comment: return dict(form_projects=form, form_activity=form_activity,  projects=project_selected,  activities_project=activities_project) so I would return that am I correct and need to rename my forms in the view or am I wrong ?

Comment: That worked with the from but my   {{=form.custom.submit}} does not work for some reason I can not submit changes made